# C# - Как передать класс в метод

Tags: c#, sql, ооп, dapper

Нужно создать метод, входным параметром которого будет класс

```
public void TablesJoin<T>(List<T> coll,object MyClass, string sql, string splitOn)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBmodel"].ConnectionString))
    {
        db.Open();

        var lookup = db.Query<T, MyClass, T>(sql, (_par_one, _par_two) =>
        {
            _par_one.MyClass = _par_two;
            return _par_one;
        },
        splitOn: splitOn).AsQueryable();

        var result = lookup.ToList();
        coll = result;
    }
}
```

ошибка в object MyClass и последующем упоминании данного класса

Плюс вопрос: корректен ли код, в ситуации с универсальным List ??
P.S. by using Dapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте еще один генерик параметр (это и есть параметр-тип)

```
public List<T> TablesJoin<T, MyClass>(string sql, string splitOn)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBmodel"].ConnectionString))
    {
        db.Open();

        var lookup = db.Query<T, MyClass, T>(sql, (_par_one, _par_two) =>
        {
            // не уверен, что должен делать этот код, но скорее всего вам                
            // придется добавить ограничение на T - 
            // т.к. ожидается наличие свойства MyClass
            _par_one.MyClass = _par_two; 
            return _par_one;
        },
        splitOn: splitOn).AsQueryable();

        return  lookup.ToList();
        // coll = result; <-- это меняет локальную ссылку на список
        // а не возвращает список наружу.
        // используйте return, чтобы вернуть объект
    }
}
```

и вызывайте с указанием конкретного класса.

Comment: Вопрос по поводу использования второго передаваемого класса 
В части `_par_one.**MyClass** = _par_two;`
Как вы и сказали, возможно надо добавить ограничение 
Visual Studio показывает ошибку 
Как правильно решить данную проблему ?

Comment: Данный код должен выполнять определённый SQL запрос и принимать из БД данные, которые будут записаны в коллекции LIST

Comment: @LevonSargsyan я просто не совсем понимаю, что у вас подразумевается под `_par_one.**MyClass**`. Это свойство объекта `_par_one`, имя которого совпадает с именем класса MyClass. Т.е. если был вызван `TablesJoin<SomeClass1, SomeClass2>`, то нужно выставить свойство `_par_one.SomeClass2`? Или что-то другое?